# SSRS 2008 R2 - Back button in a linked report doesn't show up

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

SSRS 2008 R2 - have set up a back button in a linked report to link back to main report when clicked on. The text box nor the image shows up when user runs report from reporting services - anyone know why?  Thank you

Comment: By Linked report, do you mean sub report? If yes, is it in the header section of the subreport? Headers and footers from Sub report does not show up on the main report.. BTW.. why do you need to create a custom back image to get back to main report? There is already one.. a small arrow to take you back to the main report..

Comment: No not a subreport.  Yes you do have to upload an image for the report.  I think I found the answer- which is you have to publish all report parts, which I missed doing.